# GNU Make target built twice before "up to date"; why not after first pass?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm missing some possibly mundane but critical understanding of how make determines if a dependency must be built. I've boiled my issue down to a very simple example.

```
build:
    mkdir -p $@

.PRECIOUS: build/%.txt
build/%.txt: build
    @echo "$*" > $@

%.zip: %.txt
    zip -jquX $@ $<
```

I feel the first run of `make build/foo.zip` should first create the "build" directory, then write "build/foo.txt", and last build "build/foo.zip" leaving "build/foo.txt". Then, all consecutive runs should have nothing to do, since no dependencies are newer than the target which depends on them.

However, I get the following output:

```
➜  make build/f.zip
mkdir -p build
zip -jquX build/f.zip build/f.txt

➜  make build/f.zip
zip -jquX build/f.zip build/f.txt

➜  make build/f.zip
make: 'build/f.zip' is up to date.
```

How can this be avoided? What is causing the second zip operation not to be skipped?

#### More information

I am using GNU Make 4.2.1 on Antergos with an ext4 filesystem inside VirtualBox.

Comment: Which filesystem is this? Does it have sub-second-precision timestamps?

Comment: Alternately, does adding a "sleep 1" to the end of each rule prevent the issue?

Comment: It is ext4, so it should.

Comment: Using directories as make targets is really buggy, historically. Try using a dummy `build/.dir-exists` file perhaps?

Comment: (I can't reproduce the issue, but I'm testing with GNU make 3.81 on an APFS filesystem).

Comment: Or, if you're willing to trust that your version isn't buggy, fix the immediate problem by using an order-only prerequisite, since adding/removing a file (i.e. the `.zip` file) **changes the timestamp of the directory**.

Comment: @o11c: Good call. Order only prerequisite for a directory is documented and works correctly. I didn't find this information before. I'll add the solution.

Comment: I just want to point out that using directories as prerequisites in makefiles is _NOT_ buggy.  It just doesn't work the way you might expect if you haven't considered it.  The manual explains how it works, which is perfectly consistent and actually can be very useful in some situations (consider wanting to run a recipe whenever a file is added, removed, or renamed in a directory...)

Answer (score 4):

With a great recommendation from @o11c, I came up with the solution. Turns out this is documented behavior. When adding a file to a directory the directory's time is updated. This doesn't happen the second run since no files are written to the folder.

According to the documentation for [prerequisite types](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html):

> Consider an example where your targets are to be placed in a separate directory, and that directory might not exist before make is run. In this situation, you want the directory to be created before any targets are placed into it but, because the timestamps on directories change whenever a file is added, removed, or renamed, we certainly don’t want to rebuild all the targets whenever the directory’s timestamp changes. One way to manage this is with order-only prerequisites: make the directory an order-only prerequisite on all the targets.

So here is the working solution. All that needed added was the `|`.

```
build:
    mkdir -p $@

.PRECIOUS: build/%.txt
build/%.txt: | build
    @echo "$*" > $@

%.zip: %.txt
    zip -jquX $@ $<
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explanation, but here's an alternative.  Since `mkdir -p` won't fail, you can drop the separate target for `mkdir build`.  This seems reliable for me on Linux, GNU Make 4.2.1 from Debian buster, and ext4:

```
.PRECIOUS: build/%.txt
build/%.txt:
    mkdir -p build
    @echo "$*" > $@

%.zip: %.txt
    zip -jquX $@ $<
```

Comment: It makes sense why this works, due to the folder not being a target dependency, but I need the directory dependency elsewhere, so it isn't a perfect solution. However, I came up with one that I'm about to post.